# Como arrastar formulário sem borda?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando implementar uma forma de arrastar meu **formulário** sem borda ao clica e manter pressionado o botão esquerdo do mouse nele, porem não obtive sucesso. Abaixo segue o exemplo de minha tentativa de implementação.

1° Criei as variaves `X` e `Y` como globais dentro da classe `frmExemploFormSemBorda` do meu **formulário** para receber a posição do mouse:

```
int X = 0;
int Y = 0;
```

2° Em seguida implementei os seguintes eventos, atribuindo os valores a `X` e `Y`.

Evento *MouseDown*:

```
private void frmExemploFormSemBorda_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) 
          return;

     X = this.Left - MousePosition.X;
     Y = this.Left - MousePosition.Y;
}
```

Evento *MouseMove*:

```
private void frmExemploFormSemBorda_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
          return;

     X = this.Left + MousePosition.X;
     Y = this.Left + MousePosition.Y;
}
```

3° E por fim, fiz a chamada dos eventos `MouseDown` e `MouseMove` no construtor da classe `frmExemploFormSemBorda` do meu **formulário:**

```
public frmExemploFormSemBorda()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(frmExemploFormSemBorda_MouseDown);
     this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(frmExemploFormSemBorda_MouseMove);
}
```

*Segue aqui o código completo do meu exemplo*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExemploFormSemBorda
{
    public partial class frmExemploFormSemBorda : Form
    {
        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;

        public frmExemploFormSemBorda()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(frmExemploFormSemBorda_MouseDown);
            this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(frmExemploFormSemBorda_MouseMove);
        }

        private void frmExemploFormSemBorda_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) 
                return;

            X = this.Left - MousePosition.X;
            Y = this.Left - MousePosition.Y;
        }

        private void frmExemploFormSemBorda_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
                return;

            X = this.Left + MousePosition.X;
            Y = this.Left + MousePosition.Y;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma.

No evento `MouseDown` é definido que o usuário clicou no form e o ponto que ele clicou é salvo na variável `clickedAt`.
No evento `MouseMove` é verificado se o usuário clicou no `form`, caso sim ele muda a posição conforme o mouse é arrastado.
O evento `MouseUp` é disparado quando o usuário soltar o botão do mouse e define a variável `mouseClicked` como `false`.

Obs.: Não sei se ficou bem claro, caso a resposta tenha ficado confusa me avise que eu a edito.

```
bool mouseClicked;
Point clickedAt;

private void form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseClicked)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - clickedAt.X, Cursor.Position.Y - clickedAt.Y);
    }
}

private void form_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) 
        return;

    mouseClicked = true;
    clickedAt= e.Location;
}

private void form_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseClicked = false;
}
```

Comment: assim que eu chegar em casa irei implementar, ai te darei um feedback, muito obrigado por esta ajuda.

Comment: jbueno muito obrigado funcionou aqui, fiz como esta na sua resposta e funcionou direitinho, cara fiquei uns dias tentando implementar e não conseguia nada, obrigado mesmo! :D